# MS Access SQL Chart Issue / Chart Disappearing

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a query that works just fine as long as the Alarms form is opened properly with `StartDate1` and `EndDate1` populated:

Query: AllAlarms

```
SELECT Table1.FtStageCd, Table1.Date,  Table1.OutAl
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.Date) Between [Forms]![Alarms]![StartDate1] And [Forms]![Alarms]![EndDate1])) 
ORDER BY Table1.Date;
```

When I create a chart in MS Access using the above query as its row source using the MS Access chart wizard it is fine until I select a legend. When I select legend in design mode and in Form/Report mode it goes blank white. Without a legend (series) it loads fine.

When I remove the `"WHERE (((Table1.Date) Between [Forms]![Alarms]![StartDate1] And [Forms]![Alarms]![EndDate1]))"` from the query above, the charts shows data normally (not sorted as I wanted, but data is shown).

I tried generating a separate report with that chart that is separate from the "Alarms" form then load the "Alarms" form first - populating the "StardDate1" and "EndDate1" and this separate isolated form still does not work (implying it doesn't sound like a timing issue).

For reference below is the row source for the chart:

```
TRANSFORM Sum([AllAlarms].[OutAl]) AS SumOfOutAl
SELECT [AllAlarms].[Date]
FROM [AllAlarms]
GROUP BY [AllAlarms].[Date]
ORDER BY [AllAlarms].[Date]
PIVOT [AllAlarms].[FtStageCd];
```

I've tried other things like creating the chart and altering it in VBA, but did not find any property useful to edit (tried applying the date range in a different manner - can't override access chart axes). I've tried not using the Access 2016 chart wizard and I simply could not get any chart to show - may be that I don't have the right reference loaded?

Comment: Provide data as text table. Are you using new Modern Charts?

Comment: Not sure what you mean as text table, besides the obvious - sharing the data here as a table. Is that what you mean? And yes this is using modern charts. For whatever reason the non-modern charts and it appears that I a missing a reference or something because I can't get any of those to show data. Other modern charts without legends work fine when using that same query.

Comment: Yes, text as opposed to inserting image. I analyze graph issues best when I can work with data. However, I cannot work with Modern Charts. Since this is a design and not programming issue, question not really suited to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised CROSSTAB works at all. AFAIK, when dynamic criteria is involved in any query that contributes to a CROSSTAB or in the CROSSTAB itself, there must be a PARAMETERS clause or CROSSTAB must specify column headings. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#Param